# Emacs 24.3 for windows, Tramp byte-code: Couldn't find a proper `ls' command

Tags: windows, emacs, tramp

24.2 works well, but 24.3 bounded tramp got following error when open remote Linux system files or directories:

```
"byte-code: Couldn't find a proper `ls' command"
```

I open tramp trace and find that, all remote search path and file path are extend by something, adding a extra "c:" at the beginning. The results is that tramp can find neither command nor file I want to open.

```
16:04:51.768000 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
16:04:51.769000 tramp-set-file-property (8) # c:/bin file-directory-p nil 
16:04:51.770000 tramp-get-file-property (8) # c:/usr/bin file-directory-p undef 
... 
16:04:59.531000 tramp-sh-handle-file-truename (5) # Check /c: 
16:04:59.532000 tramp-get-file-property (8) # c:/c: file-attributes-integer undef 
... 
16:04:51.773000 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil 
16:04:51.773000 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # chunksize 0 
16:04:51.773000 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # last-cmd-time (20809 28067 773000 0) 
16:04:51.774000 tramp-send-string (10) # test -d c\:/usr/bin 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?
```

Anyone know something about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after switching to Emacs 24.3. The solution was to upgrade to the latest Tramp 2.2.7. Here is what I did:

1. downloaded http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tramp/tramp-2.2.7.tar.gz
2. unpacked the archive to my ~/.emacs.d/src. I am using emacs-starter-kit which adds this directory and all its subdirectories to the load-path. Otherwise follow the instructions in the Tramp's INSTALL file.
3. used Cygwin bash to configure and compile the files. I don't use Cygwin's Emacs normally but it is convenient to have it for occasions like this.
4. deleted the old tramp's el and elc files in my emacs/lisp/net for safety.
5. restarted Emacs of course.

Do M-x tramp-version to make sure it is installed correctly. Now tramp works everywhere (dired, eshell, shell, etc).

Comment: Thanks AlexV, I compiled and installed 2.2.7 according to your steps. The extra c: is eliminated now. And I can connect to remote linux server and list files with Dired. However, when I tried to open a remote file with pscp, it fails with 6 times authentication failure, but I'm sure I entered correct password. Then I can not open file, tramp fails with message "file exits, but cannot be read". Do you possibly saw the problem before too？

Comment: BTW, I copied the pscp command out from tramp trace, and run it manually in cmd window, it works fine. "D:/Program Files/emacs-24.3/bin/cmdproxy.exe -c pscp -l XXXXX -sftp -p -q -r "XXXXX@server:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.C" "c:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/tramp.7216api.C" && echo tramp_exit_status 0 || echo tramp_exit_status 1w"

Comment: I do not use the pscp method, only plink/plinkx and ssh. Did you try setting `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` and then monitoring buffers `*tramp/pscp...*` and `*debug tramp/pscp...*`? It could be some executable not found on the other end or some variable having some stale value in your emacs session.

Comment: I found that, all inline transfer method can succeed, but external transfer methods such like psftp, pscp will fail with authentication error. After 6 times tries, connection is broken. I will open another thread to ask for this question. Thanks again for your help on this!

Comment: I don't want to install Cygwin for just this. Is it expectable that the next Emacs release will fix this or should I file a bug?

Comment: I found out a bug report (http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14030) has been filed on this. There one may read of a simple work-around: byte compile (emacs-install-path)/lisp/net/tramp-sh.el. I have confirmed that this does indeed work.

Comment: I was not able to get either fix to work (installing 2.2.7, or re-byte-compiling tramp-sh.el) until I also deleted the cached information in ~/.emacs.d/tramp. After applying the fix but before deleting this cache, all remote sites I'd attempted to access before the bug-fix continued to fail, while accessing new sites began to work.

Answer (score 19):

Merging the [answer by @AlanThird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441606/282729) and the comment by @uscjeremy, here is what worked for me *(GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN, Windows XP/SP3/32):*

1. Byte compile `tramp-sh.el` (adapt path accordingly):

   ```
   (byte-compile-file "C:/Program Files (X86)/emacs/lisp/net/tramp-sh.el")
   ```
2. Exit Emacs.
3. Delete Tramp cache: `~/.emacs.d/tramp`
4. Start Emacs.

See also [bug report #14030](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14030) on gnu.org.

Comment: According to a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381061/emacs-tramp-mode-under-windows-7-using-plink-method doing "M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections" might save the hassle of restarting emacs and deleting the file.

Comment: @Alan: no, for me it did not help. I had to restart an Emacs anyway.

Answer (score 8):

It seems this is a bug in tramp but you don't need to upgrade tramp, all you have to do is recompile tramp-sh.el on a Windows box. See the bug report [here](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14030) for more information.

Enter this on the scratch buffer:

```
(byte-compile-file "C:/Program Files/emacs/lisp/net/tramp-sh.el")
```

adjusting the path to match your install, then type <kbd>Ctrl-Meta-x</kbd> to recompile the file. If it complains about permissions you might need to restart emacs using the "run as administrator" option in Windows.

Once the file is recompiled type <kbd>M-x</kbd> *tramp-cleanup-all-connections* in order to reset the tramp connection cache. This will close any tramp connections you have open.

Comment: Doesn't work over here *(GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN*, *Windows XP/SP3/32).* I successfully byte compiled `tramp-sh.el`, then restarted Emacs, and there still is the error message: `byte-code: Couldn't find a proper `ls' command`

Answer (score 2):

Using `eval-expression` with `(byte-compile-file ..)` didn't work for me, but the following did:

1. Open emacs as administrator (right click on emacs button on taskbar, right click on emacs icon in resulting popup, click 'Run as Administrator')
2. Use Alt-X to do the compilation rather than eval-expression: `M-x byte-compile-file`: c:/Program Files/emacs-24.3/lisp/net/tramp-sh.el
3. Enter `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` in original emacs window, then try opening your remote file again.