# emacs tramp mode under windows 7, using plink method

Tags: windows, emacs, putty, plink, tramp

I'm trying to get tramp working under emacs 24.3 (tramp version 2.2.6-24.3) on windows 7 and I'm almost there. I've got putty/plink installed and in the path. Here's what's in my .emacs:

```
;;; TRAMP for remote editing ;;;
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "plink"
      tramp-default-user "dbraze"
      tramp-default-host "camille.haskins.edu"
      )
```

when I do M-x find-file /plink::
I'm prompted for a password. When I type it in all seems well, but eventually the connection fails. This is what I end up with in my *Messages* buffer:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for dbraze@camille.haskins.edu using plink...
Tramp: Sending command `plink -l dbraze  -ssh camille.haskins.edu && exit || exit'
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Tramp: Sending Password
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on `camille.haskins.edu'
Tramp: Opening connection for dbraze@camille.haskins.edu using plink...failed
completion--some: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

When I check, I see that plink continues to run. 
If I repeat the same find-file command, I get:

```
cond: Couldn't find a proper `ls' command
```

(The remote machine is running a fairly recent version of the opensuse linux distro. GNU ls is there and works fine if I ssh in directly.) If I kill plink, I can go through the same steps to the same end. Any thoughts on what's wrong or how best to troubleshoot? thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540223/emacs-24-3-for-windows-tramp-byte-code-couldnt-find-a-proper-ls-command)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I'd seen that Q&A but was unable to get a solution out of it originally. After pushing a little harder on it, I was able to get things working by first byte compiling tramp-sh.el, then doing M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections and finally restarting emacs. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540223/emacs-24-3-for-windows-tramp-byte-code-couldnt-find-a-proper-ls-command/18764972#18764972